# How co I setup auto generated monthly report email of analytics for firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I've been sending out weekly and monthly analytics reports to my team members via email.
On google analytics, we can set it up by clicking "SHARE".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1ohg.png)

But on Google analytics for firebase, I can't find that option.
Is it possible to send out weekly and monthly email reports of google analytics for firebase?
If so, how can I set it up?

Please let me know the answer of this question, or to be described the web page.

Comment: Have you been able to find a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever find away to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find to solve it.

Comment: Is there a suggested workaround for this?